# On terminal I see PHP 5.3.29, but in browser I am getting PHP 5.5.9. Please help

Tags: 14.04, php

I want to install php 5.3.29 in Ubuntu 14.04. I have tried following this post:
[Installing PHP 5.3 in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/462718/175814)

Got it work. I am getting php version as 5.3.29 while I am in terminal.

I created index.php under `/var/www/html/` with the code:

```
phpinfo();

<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

I am getting PHP version as 5.5.9. Am I missing any setting?

I want to work in PHP 5.3.29

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question you linked has multiple answers suggesting different solutions. Which one did you try to follow? (Note that each of them has an individual “share” link.)

Comment: I have followed this:    `sudo -i
wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
tar -xvf php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.29
./configure
make
make install`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg --status php5-common`?

Comment: You should not have an apt-get/dpkg package for php5 when compiling it from source as well - the two will conflict and the version in the packages will always supersede the other version when the software gets updated.