# PHP code comes as it is in browser

Tags: apache2, php

I have installed PHP as given in link
[Installing PHP 5.3 in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462673/installing-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-14-04/462718#462718?newreg=56722ea6f8124ce0985f7a856145bfec).

- In the terminal: `php -v` command show correct version.
- When I run the file from the browser `http://localhost/a.php`, code comes as it is.

What to do to execute the code?

Comment: Do you have a web server like Apache installed? It looks like you do not have it installed or properly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that PHP is not being interpreted because the webserver does not know how to handle it. Is `mod-php` installed? Try the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
$ sudo a2enmod php5
```

Did you try to configure FCGI, maybe? In that case there is probably an error in your configuration.