# Cannot compile PHP 5.3.29 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, php, compiling

I am having issues in compiling the PHP 5.3.29 on Ubuntu 16.04

My question:
Say if I compile PHP on earlier version of ubuntu and copy it over to Ubuntu 16.04.
Will it work as expected or it will fail?

Comment: The libraries it's expecting will be different.  You can't safely just 'copy' data over.  Also keep in mind that 5.3.29 is *ancient* and probably won't compile with the latest libraries lying around.

Comment: I think you will not get succesfully to install php 5.3.29, Ondrej (https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) has older PHP repositories, but the earlier he has is 5.6

Answer (score 1):

I use ubuntu 16.04, and all work's fine.
Here example how install php5.x.x [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462673/installing-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-14-04)

## Pre-requisites

You will need these two extra packages if you don't have them:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libxml2-dev
```

## Install PHP

In terminal:

```
wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
tar -xvf php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.29
./configure
make
make test # Neither mandatory nor a bad idea.
sudo make install
```

The instructions will untar the source build and they will install php in your system.

Comment: Far better :) will delete my comment above