# Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 5.3 installing

Tags: server, 18.04, php, sqlite

I have on my server Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit with Plesk the PHP 5.3 with the instructions [Can I install PHP 5.3.5 on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052746/can-i-install-php-5-3-5-on-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts) Installed

So far, he has carried out the installation without error messages.

However, PHP 7.2.15 is preinstalled and connected to Plesk on my server. If I call `phpinfo()` I also see the 7.2 version.

```
php --version
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Feb 24 2019 16:49:48)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

I can not change the PHP version on Plesk. How can I disable this or does Apache work with 5.3? That my applications in PHP 5.3 do not access the 7.2?

under / etc / php I see only the folder 7.2 but not 5.3.
What does not fit here yet?

Comment: See: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213930125-How-to-enable-additional-PHP-version-available-in-Plesk- and https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000769793-How-to-install-remove-additional-PHP-versions-provided-by-Plesk