# Setup PHP5 with MySQL module in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I'm trying to setup legacy PHP project which uses PHP5 in WSL(Ubuntu 20.04). I'm facing some difficulties while installing PHP5 and MySQL module. I've configured the PHP5 environment but couldn't install a MySQL module. I'm facing error message as `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`. I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/462718/1631351) answer to setup PHP5.

I know there are some security vulnerabilities in older PHP version and I'm not going to run this legacy app in production.

Could anyone point to ppa which has PHP5 MySQL modules? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using [the ondrej repo](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) for your PHP libraries? Or are you using something else?

Comment: I'm using `ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/php53` repo

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `--with-mysql` flag in the `./configure` command?

Comment: I tried now it didn't help. First I used `./configure` command without any flags. How can I enable mysql now? Should I remove php and install it from scratch again?

Comment: try this? `sudo apt-get install php53-mod-mysql`

Comment: @Cagri Yep I tried this too and getting following error message `php53-mod-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1) but it is not installable`

Comment: @Mdumanoj were you able to install the package? I am also having the same error,

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth, No. We decided to upgrade the PHP version