# Installing PHP5.3 for Ubuntu 20.4/22.4 for LAMP

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, apache2, php

I'm trying to install PHP5.3 on an Ubuntu server, I've tried the following:

- [Installing PHP 5.3 in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462673/installing-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-14-04#comment1014265_462707) (Make has errors and then stops apache server)
- https://gist.github.com/szihaj/b1c2e6e14eb4dd939f57e0eb46a47ab1 (ppa not compatible with this version of Ubuntu I get the following error https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Rz2zo0m88rrxqrfn)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Given the age of PHP 5.3, it is unlikely that you’ll find a reliable repository offering a direct install for 22.04 or newer. That said, Docker is made for situations like this and would be the most reliable, repeatable, and responsible way to have an EOL version of PHP on a current release of Ubuntu 

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this below command to install which is compatible with ubuntu 22.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
```

you can find the details as shown below
Go to the URL: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas
Search cappelikan and you will find the details for the ppa supporting Ubuntu 22.04
[image]

Thanks

Comment: How do I get php5.3 from this ppa?